# NSMutableArray deep saving

Tags: ios

my application's model is made of a NSMutableArray containing some other NSMutableArrays each containing a certain number of NSDictionaries, is there any way to store the main array deeply (I mean storing it and all of its content) without using core data since at the moment I still don't know how to use it? At the moment I know how to use NSUserDefaults, is there a way to deeply save the array using NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array and all of its contents (including the dictionaries) contain only [Property List](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html) compatible objects you can just put it into the `NSUserDefaults`.

Property List compatible classes are:

- `NSString`
- `NSDate`
- `NSData`
- `NSNumber`
- `NSValue`
- `NSArray`
- `NSDictionary`

Answer (score 0):

Try either [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:rootArray forKey:@"myKey"];

...

NSArray *savedArray = [defaults objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

if your data is small or [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) if it's larger

```
// To save to disk
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:rootArray toFile:@"filePath"];

// To load from disk
NSArray *savedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"filePath"];
```

or you could look at the sqlite3 C wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

To follow from Nikolai's answer - if you are putting your own custom objects into the arrays and dictionaries make sure that they can be serialized.

You can read more about it in the [Archives and Serialization Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html)

Comment: Making them `NSCoding` compliant is not enough: To put them into property lists you have to serialize them to NSData manually. Remember that the property list format is not extendable to store custom types.

Comment: I don't believe I said anything to contradict that.

Comment: I don't believe I said anything that implies your contradiction :) I added the comment to make clear that `NSCoding` does not change property list serialization which you've been referring to indirectly.